# React Router Dom - Go Back and keep state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router` version 5.3

I am navigating to a page like this, and setting state in it:

```
<Button
    className="btn-neutral"
    color="default"
    size="sm"
    onClick={() => {
        props.onGetInputData(
            props.applicationData.uniqueIdentifier,
            props.applicationData.decisionLogId
        );
        props.history.push({
            pathname: "/admin/input",
            state: {
                scoreCardDetail: props.location.state.scoreCardDetail
            }
        });
    }}
>
    Input
</Button>
```

However, when I do `props.history.goBack();` the page goes to the previous page on the stack, but the state gets lost.

Is there any way I can go to the previous page and keep the state?

Comment: Did you try to use Redux? It is a javascript library for managing and centralizing application state. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a history router to go that that state that was pushed together with the location? If you keep your state and navigate back in history, it would be rather strange UX.

Comment: Yes, persist the state *somewhere* (*React context, Redux, localStorage,...*) after the route transition. Route state is transient, it only exists *during* the transition. If you don't capture and navigate elsewhere, it's gone.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will move the state to Redux